# Eliminar Precio Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de desaparecer el precio en woocommerce a través de la cadena de consulta.

Lo que necesito hacer es aquí el ejemplo:

```
www.example.com/product-show (muestra url normal y precio)
www.example.com/product-show?noprice (precio oculto)
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: (Veo que ya has realizado preguntas en la plataforma, haciéndolas en español), entonces por traduce tu pregunta pues estas en SO en español, en caso contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual seria el problema que tenes?

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de lograr lo que quieres, depende mucho de si estás usando las plantillas por defecto de WooCommerce, si es así con poner el siguiente código en el functions.php de tu tema debería hacer lo que pides:

```
// Quitar del hook woocommerce_single_product_summary la funcion que imprime el precio
add_action('template_redirect', 'wc_product_single_remove_price_on_param');
function wc_product_single_remove_price_on_param() {
    // Comprueba que estamos en el detalle de un producto y que viene el parametro en la url
    if ( is_singular('product') && isset($_GET['noprice']) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
    }
}
```